# How to make Azure nodejs webapp re-run npm install?

Tags: node.js, azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service, npm-install

I'm running a Node webapp on Azure.
I deploy the app using the "local git" method.
Every time I make changes to my source, commit, and then deploy with `git push azure master`, the code on the site is updated, as expected.

But one of my recent changes included adding a new package to my `package.json` file. Now when I deploy, my files are updated, but azure doesn't seem to re-run `npm install`, and the new modules are not installed. This means that the app doesn't start: when my code calls `require('missingModuleName')` it gets a fatal error and stops.

Last time I had this problem, I removed the app from Azure, and created a new one from scratch. But I hope that there's a simpler solution.

I see (at https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment) that on deployment "For Node sites, Kudu runs 'npm install' in the wwwroot folder". I'm not sure whether the standard "local git" deployment method invokes the Kudu deployment process. Do I need to create a deployment hook (as described in https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-hooks)?

The installation log shows: 
`` 2017-07-29T07:59:51  Updating branch 'master'.
2017-07-29T07:59:52  Updating submodules.
2017-07-29T07:59:52  Preparing deployment for commit id '556a34aab5'.
2017-07-29T07:59:52  Running custom deployment command...
2017-07-29T07:59:52  Running deployment command...
2017-07-29T07:59:52    Command: deploy.cmd
2017-07-29T07:59:53    Handling node.js deployment.
2017-07-29T07:59:53    KuduSync.NET from: 'D:\home\site\repository' to: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot'
2017-07-29T07:59:53    Copying file: 'package.json'
2017-07-29T07:59:53    Looking for app.js/server.js under site root.
2017-07-29T07:59:53    Using start-up script server.js
2017-07-29T07:59:55    Node.js versions available on the platform are: 0.6.20, 0.8.2, 0.8.19, 0.8.26, 0.8.27, 0.8.28, 0.10.5, 0.10.18, 0.10.21, 0.10.24, 0.10.26, 0.10.28, 0.10.29, 0.10.31, 0.10.32, 0.10.40, 0.12.0, 0.12.2, 0.12.3, 0.12.6, 4.0.0, 4.1.0, 4.1.2, 4.2.1, 4.2.2, 4.2.3, 4.2.4, 4.3.0, 4.3.2, 4.4.0, 4.4.1, 4.4.6, 4.4.7, 4.5.0, 4.6.0, 4.6.1, 4.8.4, 5.0.0, 5.1.1, 5.3.0, 5.4.0, 5.5.0, 5.6.0, 5.7.0, 5.7.1, 5.8.0, 5.9.1, 6.0.0, 6.1.0, 6.2.2, 6.3.0, 6.5.0, 6.6.0, 6.7.0, 6.9.0, 6.9.1, 6.9.2, 6.9.4, 6.9.5, 6.10.0, 6.11.1, 7.0.0, 7.1.0, 7.2.0, 7.3.0, 7.4.0, 7.5.0, 7.6.0, 7.7.4, 7.10.0, 7.10.1, 8.0.0, 8.1.4.
2017-07-29T07:59:55    Selected node.js version 8.1.4. Use package.json file to choose a different version.
2017-07-29T07:59:55    Selected npm version 5.0.3
2017-07-29T07:59:56    Updating iisnode.yml at D:\home\site\wwwroot\iisnode.yml
2017-07-29T07:59:56    npm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\0.10.28\node.exe but npm is using D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\8.1.4\node.exe itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.
2017-07-29T08:00:03    npm WARN passport-azure-ad-login-oidc@0.0.1 No repository field.
2017-07-29T08:00:03    up to date in 7.206s
2017-07-29T08:00:03    npm WARN passport-azure-ad-login-oidc@0.0.1 No license field.
2017-07-29T08:00:03

2017-07-29T08:00:03    Finished successfully.
2017-07-29T08:00:03  Running post deployment command(s)...
2017-07-29T08:00:03  Deployment successful. ``

Comment: To help isolate, what happens if you manually run `npm install` from the `site/wwwroot` using Kudu Console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with `package-lock.json`. I was using an old npm version 3  locally, and it didn't create a package lock file (and I wasn't ready for shrinkwrap).

But the newer npm version 5 on Azure *did* create a `package-lock.json`. That seems to take precedence over the `package.json`.

So I upgraded npm locally (took a while to find that I needed `nodist npm latest` to do it), and added the `package-lock.json` to my git repo. Then when it deployed, npm took quite some time but it installed everything for me.