# NodeJS application deployment issue

Tags: node.js, git, azure, deployment, visual-studio-code

Deployed NodeJS application to Azure from VS Code like mentioned here: [Deploy NodeJS app to Azure from VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45625131/630169) successfully - first initial commit:

```
$ git push azure master
...
remote: Updating branch 'master'.
remote: Updating submodules.
...
```

Then added `dotenv-extended` module to `app.js`:

```
require('dotenv-extended').load();
```

**npm** added `"dotenv-extended": "^2.0.1"` to `package.json` file. After that committed, pushed to github, then pushed to azure same way like above.

However **in 2nd time** Azure did not perform submodules update and `dotenv-extended` was not installed on Azure in `/node_modules/*` which is added to `.gitignore` on my side. This caused application exception so forced to go to azure and run `npm install dotenv-extended` or `npm update` manually.

**In 3rd time** deployment Azure printed:

```
remote: Updating branch 'master'.
remote: Updating submodules.
...
remote: npm WARN MyApp@1.0.0 No description
remote: removed 15 packages in 31.134s
remote: npm WARN MyApp@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

and when I checked `dotenv-extended` was erased again even if I installed it manually previously.

- Why did this happen, why azure did not run `remote: Updating submodules` in second time?
- How to fix this if I need to add some modules later?
- Is it possible to fix or extend some post-deployment script on Azure to add `npm update` command?
- Or install them manually which is not good?
- Or there is another way to deploy without git?

> P.S. Think proposed solution
>   [Git push to azure websites with submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11939728/630169) will not work as Git Azure
>   erases modules for some reason.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939728/git-push-to-azure-websites-with-submodule

Comment: @YeLwinSoe thanks for the link however some not quite clear: could You explain this more detailed please - what need to do? Add `/node_modules/*` as submodule to main repo? I do not want to commit it on github however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems some Azure issue it uses `kudusync` **npm** module for `repository` and `wwwroot` synchronizations and works wrong way. Following sequence helped me to solve the issue:

- Go to `Kudu` in Azure,
- Open `Debug Console -> CMD` there
- Execute:

  - cd `D:\home\site\repository>`
  - `npm udpate`
  - cd `D:\home\site\wwwroot>`
  - `npm udpate`
    For some reason Azure script install npm modules in `repository` dir only on first deployment, and do not update it further. Above commands allow to synchronize `repository` and `wwwroot` directories and prevent removing packages not present in `repository` from `wwwroot`. However need to do this on every added package.

Works fine now after all of above. People [suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45394490/630169) to commit `package-lock.json`, however this solution had not helped me: Azure deployment script uninstalls modules not present in `D:\home\site\repository>` from `D:\home\site\wwwroot>` and I get above error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's having trouble loading modules. By default, Azure Web Apps’ deployment task uses `npm install --production` command to install the dependencies in your package.json, which will skip all the dependencies configured in `devDependencies` section. So please make sure `dotenv-extended` is placed in `dependencies`.

Comment: The module is in `dependencies`, `devDependencies` is empty on my side. Any other solution?

Comment: You can setup a [Custom Deployment Script](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Custom-Deployment-Script) to enable you adding `npm update` command for your app. See [Custom Deployment Scripts For Microsoft Azure Web App (Website) Using Git Deployment](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/38417491924/azurewebsitecustomdeploymentpart1/#.WZOjJFEjGUl).

Comment: Custom Deployment Script method overrides Azure default method and sources not copied to `wwwroot`. Need another or more detailed solution.

Answer (score 0):

> **Note.** Custom Deployment Script method, mentioned below, overrides Azure default method and sources not copied to `wwwroot`. Need another
>   or more detailed solution.

According to [Custom Deployment Script](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Custom-Deployment-Script) added a file to the root of my git repository with the name `.deployment` and the content:

```
[config]
command = cd %DEPLOYMENT_TARGET% && echo "npm update ..." && npm update --quiet
```

Works for now however increases deployment time, will see more if another module added.